# How do i split a string into 3 different one's in a batch script?

Tags: string, batch-file

I have been working on a encryption program for a bit now and i have figured out how to encrypt the text and stuff but now i need to revert it.

My output will look like:
1.234.23415.513513.135524.{111}[1234]

The numbers before the full stop is a character or space, {} is my first key and [] is my second key.
The thing thats giving me a hard time is taken the {111} and [1234] and setting them both to their own strings/variables. This is needed so i can convert it back.

So my question is how do i take the string:
"1.234.23415.513513.135524.{111}[1234]" And set the values between the {}, [] and the numbers and set them to 3 different strings?

(not english please pardon my bad grammer and spelling)
(the key length wont change)

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1-3 delims={[]}" %a in ( "1.234.23415.513513.135524.{111}[1234]") do echo %a %b %c` (for usage in a batch file, replace each `%` with `%%`. Read `for /f` for how it works and more information. (PS: I removed the `encryption` tag, as your question has nothing to do with encryption, but with string handling.

Comment: Careful! Crypto is *very hard* to get right. Wise programmers don't entrust other peoples' secrets to crypto modules they wrote themselves, unless their names are Bruce Schneier or Whit Diffie.

Comment: Thank yall also i m not planning to use this with others its just to learn skills. Also i call it encryption cuz in my code i use the 2 keys to convert text to numbers and then run the keys using math to generate text that you can only figure out using the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Full credit to @Stephan)
This is not my answer but people will look at the answers, not the comments.

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims={[]}" %a in ( "1.234.23415.513513.135524.{111}[1234]") do set "string=%a" & set "key1=%b" & set "key2=%c"
```

(For usage in a batch file, replace each `%` with `%%`. Read `for /f` for how it works and more information.)